# crop and keep the names on multiples images on magick

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagick

I would like to crop multiple images files and keep the same name or add a "_2" at the end of the name.

any idea how to do it?

I tried this

```
magick *jpg -set filename:base "%[basename]" -fuzz 90% "%[filename:base]_2.jpg"
```

Comment: I think the right way is this:

magick *jpg -set filename:base "%[basename]" -fuzz 90% -trim "%[filename:base]_2.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

To just keep the same name use [`magick mogrify`](https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php). This works exactly like `magick` or `magick convert` but overwrites the input file, so there is no output specification. It is quite simple to use on a set of files:

```
magick mogrify [parameters] file [file...]
```

Comment: FYI Don't use magick convert in Imagemagick 7, use just magick.